# Manage Print Queue on print server without admin access

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

Is there a commercial or free product that would allow me to delegate access to the print queue and spooler to non-administrators?  I would like to give access to support team members without making them administrators on the box.  Is this possible?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you check Security properties of your server, in roles > print and documents services> print management printer server> right click server name > properties. You have option for manage server. It might be what you are looking for. you can also give you support team right to restart spooler.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with native permissions, happily. One of the permissions you can set on printers is the "Manage Documents" permission, which allows support team members to do such useful things as purge stuck documents and empty queues. They'll need "Manage this printer" to do things like change printer-drivers and settings.